# Why is it the case that, if $y= f(x,z) = x\times z$ , then $\partial y / \partial x = z$ and $\partial y / \partial z= x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

I would like to derive, using differentials,  the product rule for single variable functions.

Apparently, this rule is a particular case of the product rule for functions of several variables.

In Bouasse, *Cours de mathématiques générales* ( p.19) , the proof of the product rule is given as an instantiation of a more general rule, namely :

If $y= f( x, z, t...)$ then $dy = \frac {\partial y}  {\partial x} dx + \frac {\partial y}  {\partial z} dz + \frac {\partial y}  {\partial t} dt$.

The application to a function $y = f(x, z) = x\times z$ gives :

$dy = \frac {\partial y}  {\partial x} dx + \frac {\partial y}  {\partial z} dz$.

**But, as notes the author : $\frac {\partial y}  {\partial x} = z$ and $ \frac {\partial y}  {\partial z}= x$.**

This allows to write :

$dy = zdx + xdz$

Which means that, in case both $x$ and $z$ are functions of some variable $t$, one can get, dividing both sides by $dt$

$ y'(t) = \frac {dy} {dt} = z \frac {dx} {dt} + x \frac {dz} {dt} = z \space  x' + x\space z' $

as desired.

What I do not understand is the remark that I printed in boldface : **$\frac {\partial y}  {\partial x} = z$ and $ \frac {\partial y}  {\partial z}= x$.**

However, this  remark is an essential step in the proof.

How do these equalities derive using the definition of function $y$ under consideration here and , maybe, the definition of " partial derivative " ?

[image]

Comment: Partial derivative is the rate of change of function when only one of arguments is changing. $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{y(x+h,z)-y(x,z)}{h}$. So when you take partial derivative $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ you just consider $z$ as constant parameter.

Comment: I should have seen this,!  thanks a lot ! @IvanKaznacheyeu

Answer (score 1):

$$
z=\frac{∂y}{∂x}\quad{and}\quad{x}=\frac{∂y}{∂z}.
$$
In the parameter **z** is assigned (as an substitution) the partial derivative and relatively of the parameter **x** the author does the same thing. As a result the **full derivative** relatively of the all parameters ($x$, $z$) will be calculated: **dy**.